# Is there a way to copy bundle resource to app folder when built finished?

Tags: ios, xcode

Actually I have a xcode workspace, containing several projects, for example, projectA and projectB, projectA is the main project, and projectB will generate a bundle file which projectA will use, is there a way to copy the bundle file to the main app folder? I know one way to do this is to drag the generated bundle file here like the below image shows, but as we have several team members and use git to manage the project, this method will use my personal folder path, and when others want to build the project, they will have to drag the bundle again. Is there a way to copy the generated bundle using relative path? Or can I use a script to do this? So everyone can just checkout the code directly without dragging the bundle manually? Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Target -> Build Phases can you just `Run Script` after that target is done to copy it to the other place?

Comment: I was wondering how to write the script, basically I just want to copy the generated file to the ipa folder like the "copy bundle resources" does.

Comment: I can't give you a ready to go recipe. I can just tell you to be ready for a bunch of trial and error but then it should work.